# read / write perl object config files

Tags: perl, config

I'm looking for a perl config file editor.  I see some great mods like:

[Config::General](http://search.cpan.org/~tlinden/Config-General-2.52/General.pm)

[Config::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~sherzodr/Config-Simple-4.59/Simple.pm)

[Config::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~rsavage/Config-Tiny-2.20/lib/Config/Tiny.pm)

However, these options tend to load **ini, yaml, json, etc..** files instead of **perl** config files.

Wouldn't it always be faster and safer in perl to load a perl config file? That way the file is loaded through an *eval* or *do* instead of parsed manually through reg exps etc. However I can't seem to find a good prewritten version of this.

[Reading and Writing Perl...](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=464358) - old perlmonks thread

[OpenPlugin::Config::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~eric/OpenPlugin-0.11/OpenPlugin/Config/Perl.pm) - potentially what i'm looking for ??

What is the best module to use?  Is there a reason *ini* file loading seems to be more popular than loading a file directly in the language it is already written in?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I would not be evaluating a random file, I will be loading my own custom perl file. This would be the same thing as loading a php config file already written in php. Anyone know of a module that uses PERL?

Answer (score 3):

Unless we're talking about gigantic config files, I wouldn't worry about the speed of loading and parsing a config file.

Regarding safety, you wouldn't want to just `eval` any old Perl code / config that you'd read from the filesystem - who knows what it will try to do? You'd want to make sure to use the `reval` method from the [Safe](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/Safe-2.35/Safe.pm) module.

Comment: So speed would not be an issue thanks. However, I would not be evaling a random perl file, it would be my own config file with one variable. Perhaps using a do statement would be equal?

Comment: I'd still recommend using the Safe module, in case your system is compromised and your config edited, or even if someone accidentally screws with it. Better `Safe` than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The project I'm working on at the moment uses Config::Any.  It's fairly easy to use and is very flexible with which types of config files that it will accept (On the synopsis it says it uses yaml, json, ini, among other ones).

In my experience using JSON or yaml seems to do the trick but I'm not well versed in the pros and cons of using each one so you'll have to decide that for yourself :).  Hope that helped ^^

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking to use a perl config though.

Comment: From the pod page: "Config::Any provides a facility for Perl applications and libraries to load configuration data from multiple different file formats. It supports XML, YAML, JSON, Apache-style configuration, Windows INI files, and even Perl code." So you could use it if you wanted. Seems pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

`eval`ing a random config file as Perl is fraught with danger. It could have anything in it, including code to wipe your hard drive. It also weakens locality of reference because you have executable code that's affecting the overall state of your program outside your program.

For configuration files, I often use XML::Simple. It's an easy way of getting basic name-value pairs.

Comment: Hi, I understand the problem with executable code, but I'm tryng to load just one variable as a hash reference like [HERE](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=464358). It would never be a random perl config file.

Comment: Except that you don't know what people have put in there when they change the configuration values in the future. Config files are for random changes by random people in the unknown future. And seriously, you're loading one value? Use a real config file method.

Comment: Rob, that's assuming that anyone else has access to change the config file or should. Anyone that has access to change a config file could just as easily change a perl module or perl file core code, depending on where you store it and your access settings. I believe the perl method is a very real method. One hash scalar can hold as many values as you want making it easier to create objects and load them. It would be the exact same thing as a php file that holds values in an associative array called $CFG or $config.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Config::Any provides Read+Write.

But if you are willing to work with Perl Data Structure for config as there are some arguments against JSON etc - you may want ot take a look at [Config::Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Perl)